# How to stop Bootstrap's responsive carousel images becoming too small in small screen/windows?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am making a website using bootstrap.
I have carousel images in the homepage, but when I make the browser window small or open it in smart phone the carousel images become too small and odd looking.

Here's what I mean:
http://www.bootply.com/BmzEiDLmC4

I would like to have an effect where the image height can remain constant and the image gets cropped on left and right when the browser window is smaller. Something like this:

http://www.fuseproject.com/

I have tried finding it on Goolge as well as Stakoverflow but can't seem to find a solution.

This might be a simple issue - but with my limited knowledge in web development I am not able to find the solution. I would really appreciate if anyone could help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Demo: https://jsbin.com/lefizo/1/

*Use background images on a fixed height .item and adjust the media queries as needed.*

**CSS:**

```
#my-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
#my-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/1500x500/333/999.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
}
#my-carousel .carousel-inner .item-2 {
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/1500x500/555/999.png)
}
#my-carousel .carousel-inner .item-3 {
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/1500x500/777/999.png)
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    #my-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
        height: 500px
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- carousel start -->

<div class="containter">

      <div class="carousel carousel-fade slide" id="my-carousel">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active item-1">
             <a href="#"></a>
       </div>
          <div class="item item-2" >
             <a href="#"></a>
       </div>
          <div class="item item-3">
             <a href="#"></a>
       </div>
        </div>
        <!--  remove the a href tag to remove link that does not need it -->

        <a href="#my-carousel" class="carousel-control left" data-slide="prev"><!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> --></a>
        <a href="#my-carousel" class="carousel-control right" data-slide="next"><!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> --></a>
            
    </div>

</div>
<!-- carousel end -->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Christina! This is the effect I am looking for.

Comment: By the way, Is this the only way to do this by using the background image method in the css? Is there any other way to do it by using the html only (not CSS). 
One more thing, what's the right way to add these image link to CSS? Should I add a separate CSS file just for images? Or should I keep them in the main custom CSS file?

Comment: This is the way to do it without fuss, you can use a script I guess or do something like fix position and a lot of math. You have to understand CSS and html to know that if you stick a real image there the edge of the image will push itself against the edge of the viewport and either it sizs down and gets too small or you get scrollbars or if you hide the scroll bars it's still not centered unless you figure on messing with the left position at a variety of breakpoints.  You would put the css after your other css in the same file or another.

Comment: Thank again Christina for the explanation! I think your method is suitable for me as I am looking for an uncomplecated solution.

Now, my site has about 30 pages and 3-4 pages have corousels with 4-5 images each. I have one custom CSS file for all the pages. So, if I include all the carousel images in the main CSS file, all the pages (or the home page) have to load all the carousel images making them heavy.

So I am wondering if it's better idea to use a separte CSS file (just for the carousel) for each page with carousel or even use internal style. Is it okay or has some potential problem?

Comment: The fewest http requests the better. Keep your css files down the minimum, use one CSS file, put all the CSS in that, use media queries or server side tech to deliver smaller images to smaller devices. Look up adaptive-images.php for server side. Look up mobile first background images in google to understand that.

Comment: what about internal CSS embedded in the html file (my site is made of plain html) that would have just the carousel images? it won't be adding to the http request right? Does this have any potential problem?

Comment: Prevents caching if you do that. http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/adding-css-to-html-with-link-embed-inline-and-import - further questions need to be new SO questions.

Comment: Thanks @BootstrapBoogie once again. I am just following your method and it's working fine. I seem to havetwo issues with it, 1: The Links are not working even if I keep the href tags. and 2: the automatic sliding of the images is sometime happening and sometime not!!
http://www.bootply.com/saikat/BmzEiDLmC4#
 **Am I supposed to start a new question, as this question is not yet fully resolved?

Comment: The question was about the image becoming smaller, that was answered. Resolving an entire issue would be separated out into other questions indicating your effort made. How you have your links inside the item set up are unknown. If the link is the entire slide, make the link position absolute with all directions 0 and display block. If it's not sliding, check to see that you have the correct settings, read the instructions on data-interval or how you can set it up in jQuery. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: "If the link is the entire slide, make the link position absolute with all directions 0 and display block." - Could you please explain this bit please? I am looking for the entire slide to be links for different pages - it's not working if I set the images as background-image.

Comment: Now everything is working fine!!
I am marking this question answered.
Thank you so much Crhistina for your help! :)